# java thread hangs while using executorService executing a oracle query

Tags: java, multithreading, oracle, jdbc

```
"pool-11-thread-1" prio=10 tid=0x0a974c00 nid=0x7210 runnable [0x3f3ad000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CStatement.t2cDefineExecuteFetch(Native Method)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CPreparedStatement.doDefineExecuteFetch(T2CPreparedStatement.java:878)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T2CPreparedStatement.java:760)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1062)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1126)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3339)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.execute(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3445)
  - locked <0x69579fb0> (a oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CPreparedStatement)
  - locked <0x66157d68> (a oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection)
  at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.CachedPreparedStatement.execute(CachedPreparedStatement.java:216)
  at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.execute(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:209)
  at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.execution.SqlExecutor.executeQuery(SqlExecutor.java:180)
  at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.mapping.statement.GeneralStatement.sqlExecuteQuery(GeneralStatement.java:205)
  at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.mapping.statement.GeneralStatement.executeQueryWithCallback(GeneralStatement.java:173)
  at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.mapping.statement.GeneralStatement.executeQueryForObject(GeneralStatement.java:104)
  at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapExecutorDelegate.queryForObject(SqlMapExecutorDelegate.java:561)
  at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapExecutorDelegate.queryForObject(SqlMapExecutorDelegate.java:536)
  at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapSessionImpl.queryForObject(SqlMapSessionImpl.java:93)
  at org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientTemplate$1.doInSqlMapClient(SqlMapClientTemplate.java:273)
  at org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientTemplate.execute(SqlMapClientTemplate.java:209)
  at org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientTemplate.queryForObject(SqlMapClientTemplate.java:271)
  at com.alipay.bipgw.common.dal.bankchannel.ibatis.IbatisBipBusiOrderDAO.queryOrderOutTime(IbatisBipBusiOrderDAO.java:319)
  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3333.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
  at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:310)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
  at com.alipay.bipgw.common.dal.monitor.DalMonitorInterceptor.invoke(DalMonitorInterceptor.java:60)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
  at $Proxy79.queryOrderOutTime(Unknown Source)
  at com.alipay.bipgw.prodcore.repository.impl.BusiOrderRepositoryImpl.queryOrderOutTime(BusiOrderRepositoryImpl.java:402)
  at com.alipay.bipgw.prodcore.listener.ProdStatusChangeTimeoutTaskListener.execute(ProdStatusChangeTimeoutTaskListener.java:148)
  at com.alipay.bipgw.prodcore.listener.ProdStatusChangeTimeoutTaskListener.access$000(ProdStatusChangeTimeoutTaskListener.java:60)
  at com.alipay.bipgw.prodcore.listener.ProdStatusChangeTimeoutTaskListener$1.run(ProdStatusChangeTimeoutTaskListener.java:104)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

the java programm like this :

```
public void onUniformEvent(UniformEvent message, UniformEventContext uContext) {
    try {
        // single thread running
        service.execute(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try{
                    execute();
                }catch(Exception e ){
                    logger.error("working error",e);
                }

            }
        });
    } catch (RejectedExecutionException e) {
        logger.error("ProdStatusChangeTimeoutTaskListener:error", e);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("ProdStatusChangeTimeoutTaskListener:error", e);
    }

}
 //omit the body
 private void execute() {.....}
```

and the execute method will not start any thread.

in two days i dump several thread dump
2013-03-04 16:54:12

```
- locked <0x695f91f0> (a oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CPreparedStatement)
- locked <0x6615a2d0> (a oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection)
```

2013-03-04 17:20:53

```
- locked <0x695f91f0> (a oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CPreparedStatement)
- locked <0x6615a2d0> (a oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection)
```

2013-03-05 10:58:30

```
- locked <0x6957bec8> (a oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CPreparedStatement)
- locked <0x66157e90> (a oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection)
```

2013-03-05 17:16:31

```
- locked <0x69579fb0> (a oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CPreparedStatement)
- locked <0x66157d68> (a oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection)
```

seems like the lock hold by jdbc client has changed, but the first two in 2013-03-04 16:54:12 and 2013-03-04 17:20:53,   they are the same

I am using a Excutors.newSingleThreadExecutor() doing a query job in backgroud, and the following task will be submit to this executor Service in 20 minutes interval, but the work thread seems to hangs while executing the query , so the following task will not be executed. It last for several days , no exception occur and no  log output at all,  somebody  can help me ? thanks

Comment: I definitely think this is an issue with locking. Please check the locks on the database to confirm this.

Comment: do you mean the table is locked on the server side??

Comment: I'd expect something along those lines... The table, or a row involved... Do you have Enterprise Manager for Oracle? That can show quite a lot of imprtant information about the current sessions in a very easy to access way

Comment: ok, i will let my dba to check the sessions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has been solved~ 
after several real time executes , out dba monitor the db server side, and find that the query  time is 210s which execeeds the query-out-time(180s), but the cancel request of the stamentent may not be effective and the db server may not response to that request . so the thread which porform the original query hangs.  the similar situation see [When I call PreparedStatement.cancel() in a JDBC application, does it actually kill it in an Oracle database?

the solution can been done by following:
add sqlprofile to the target table，and make sql using skip scan  to short the query time.

but the deepest reason why hanging will occur is still unknown.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely to lie in your actual query - is it a long running task?  Do you know how long on average it takes to complete?

Its possible (but this is dependent on the query itself) that a previous query is locking tables which in turn block later ones.

The first thing I would do it to verify that the query does indeed complete within 20 minutes, and does so consistently.  After you know that it does you can then investigate other possible causes for the hanging behavior you're seeing.

When the query is running I'd also suggest that you check the explain plan for your query (see what its doing - whats taking the most time etc).  I'd also check that the relevant statistics are up to date (perhaps less of an issue on newer versions of Oracle)

Comment: 1) the query time vary between 1ms to 170s  2) the query is only query , no lock table,  3) at db side , there seems no alert, if the query really last for 20minute , there will be alert.

Comment: Ok - are you sure that its completely finished once executed?  No table locks in place afterwards?  If you're sure that the DB side is "clean" after execution, then I guess the next part to check is the Java side - are there any inter-dependent classes that might cause an issue?  Post a sample of the code might be helpful here

Comment: the current problem is that the worker thread is alive, but seem not working any more, so no more query is executed now,  iam quite sure there is no inter-dependent classes and there is no  program secting to lock that table.

Comment: Ok - how about adding some logging at the start and end of your run method above? logger.info("starting work"); as the first statement of the run method and then logger.info("finished work"); as the last (after the catch block)?  You could then at least verify that the block is finishing.  If it doesnt then subsequent tasks wont run (as you have a single threaded executor)

Comment: in execute method , i have the log like "job start", and "job ends " at the end of execute method ,  the first few runs go completly, but suddenly ,only the "job start" logged out, the  "job ends "  dismissed, and after then, no log come out anymore

Comment: Your updates above do imply some sort of locking at the db level - is it possible that some other process is locking tables your process needs?  And perhaps the two cause some sort of deadlock between them? I'm afraid at this stage its probably going to be difficult to assist without further code/context